# How can I deny access to the file xmlrpc.php to all virtual hosts in my OpenLiteSpeed server?

Tags: .htaccess, linode, openlitespeed, cyber-panel

I am running an OpenLiteSpeed server with CyberPanel on a Linode. I need to block access to the WordPress file xmlrpc.php for all domains, as it is a security concern. I know how to block the file for each domain using .htaccess, but there has got to be an easier way for this to apply to all domains on the server.

Thank you for you help in advance!

Comment: https://openlitespeed.org/kb/access-control/    you can create a context , and then copy-paste the generated lines into all your vhosts

Comment: It is disabled by CyberPanel

Comment: no ,only rewrite rule tab is disaled, the context still works as it is